# Where is the definitive home for amavisd-new-2.12?

Tags: amavis

I have `amavis` installed from `epel`, and it reports

```
# systemctl status amavisd
● amavisd.service - Amavis mail content checker
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/amavisd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-09-17 14:39:27 UTC; 2 days ago
     Docs: http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/#doc
# amavisd -V
amavisd-new-2.12.0 (20190725)
```

I'm trying to find the documentation, but, AFAICT (including based on the above output of `systemctl status`) IJS is the definitive home for amavisd-new, and yet 2.12 doesn't seem to exist. The soft link to "latest" points to 2.8, and the [absolutely most recent](https://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/#new) listed is amavisd-new-2.11.1. Maybe my google-foo is just weak, but ... where is the definitive home for version 2.12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://gitlab.com/amavis/amavis/ is the location linked to in the latest release announcement on the [user list](https://lists.amavis.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/amavis-users).